# How can I perform another action after saving a <Create /> form?

Tags: react-admin

I have a  which performs a POST to change the users password. When a password change occurs the API invalidates all access tokens so the user must re-authenticate.

I need to somehow get the password they just entered and re-authenticate with the userLogin().

How can I do this after the form is saved and a 200 comes back from the API?

Comment: Please post your current code, with details about what is currently working and the specific lines of code that are causing problems, with any browser errors you might be seeing. [Help on creating solid SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)